# Change relative url with CURL

Tags: php, curl, relative-path, relative-url

I'm trying to scrape some websites using CURL. In order to change the relative URL's I have inserted this:

```
 $curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```

It's working good for most websites but not all of them. For instance this website "[NS Website](http://www.ns.nl/)" show's no effect at all, meaning the URL's are completed with my domain as base url: mydomain.com/css.css

This is the complete code Im using:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);

curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;

?>
```

[Live example at phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4hb-9pm)

Comment: That's because you are using a regular expression to add your element.  Easiest way would be with a DOMDocument.  The specific reason that it is not working for your linked example site is because it has `<head profile=...>` instead of just `<head>`.

Comment: @Jon What do you mean with "DOMDocument"? Javascript?

Comment: @Youss http://php.net/DOMDocument - Additional this does not work for websites that have a differen `<base href` already.

Comment: But -1 from my side: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. Better first understand *why* things do not work, not just dump code here and just ask why does not work. I bet you are more clever than this.

Comment: @hakre I didn't know why it doesn't work, therefore I couldn't not do  research for this problem. You are free to downvote:) (although it doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the regular expression.

You are looking for `<head>`, but the given example's website has a `<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">`.

Replace your regular expression with :

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<head.*>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```